# download csv from filepath in java

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv, read.csv

I am trying to download csv file from the filepath that is saved in db. I have to read the csv file from filepath and download it when hitting the endpoint. Error I am getting says no converter for class BufferedReader with preset Content-Type 'application-csv'. I think the type I have with response entity BufferedReader is not taking my content-type as csv. I have seen resource type with response entity working fine. And I don't want csv to be generated, I already have it, i just have to read it and download it.

```
@GetMapping("/export")
    public CompletableFuture <ResponseEntity<BufferedReader>> getCSVFile(@RequestParam Integer reportdt,
            @RequestParam("conId") String conId) throws IOException {
        

        CSVFilePath csvFilePath = csvFilePathRepository.findByConIdAndReportdt(conId, reportdt);
        File file = new File(csvFilePath.getFilepath());
        //FileInputStream csvfile = new FileInputStream(csvFilePath.getFilepath());
        FileReader newfile = new FileReader(csvFilePath.getFilepath());
        String fileName = file.getName();
        if(file.exists()) {
        return CompletableFuture
                .completedFuture(ResponseEntity.ok()
                  .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
                  .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/csv"))
                  .body(new BufferedReader(newfile)));            
        } else {
            return CompletableFuture
                    .completedFuture(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(new BufferedReader(newfile)));    
        }
    }
```

Here is the error log.
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R49Co.jpg)

Comment: Should probably have to write a AbstractHttpMessageConverter and register it on app startup by extending the converters.

Comment: Here is a good reference on how to do it: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/csv-msg-converter.html